# Message sender's name not changing in Slack using Python Bolt SDK

Tags: python-3.x, slack-bolt

Below is my code where using the `username` attribute (`username="MyNotifications"`) I'm trying to change the sender's name in the Slack message when posted to a channel however the name always appears as the Slack application name instead:-

```
from typing import Optional
import os
import logging
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from slack_bolt import App
from slack_bolt.adapter.socket_mode import SocketModeHandler
from slack_sdk import WebClient

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
env_path = Path('.') / '.env'
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)

SLACK_VERIFICATION_TOKEN = os.environ['SLACK_VERIFICATION_TOKEN']
SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET = os.environ['SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET']
SLACK_BOT_TOKEN = os.environ['SLACK_BOT_TOKEN']
SLACK_APP_TOKEN = os.environ['SLACK_APP_TOKEN']

SLACK_MAIN_CHANNEL = "<channel id>"

# Install the Slack app and get xoxb- token in advance
app = App(token=SLACK_BOT_TOKEN, signing_secret=SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET)


@app.event("message")
def handle_message(event, say, context):
    text = event["text"]
    source_channel = event["channel"]
    if "metadata" in event and source_channel == SLACK_MAIN_CHANNEL:
        target_channel = event["metadata"]["event_payload"]["channel_name"]
        print(f"Received message '{text}' from user in channel {source_channel}")
        app.client.chat_postMessage(channel=target_channel, text=text, username="MyNotifications")
        print("message sent...")
    else:
        print("skipped...")
```

I have referred to this Slack [documentation](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#arg_username).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting into Slack's documentation in detail, I was finally able to solve this. I added the scope `chat:write.customize` in the Bot Token scopes which helped me to customize the sender's name.

Answer (score 1):

You indeed need to request the `chat:write.customize` scope in order to post as another entity using the `chat.postMessage` method.  There's a section dedicated to this on the method's page which also mentions how to customize the app's emoji as well: https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#authorship.